# Can Hibernate Validator be used as component outside Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator, bean-validation

I am trying to add validation for message payload (which are json). I am using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org)  Json processor for data binding, which works quite well for me, using bean methods and occasional annotation or two.

But beyond data binding, I would like to declaratively validate actual values: and specifically I prefer annotations over any external schema (DRY principle, keeping code & constraints fully in-sync). And so I am looking for a simple validation library to do this.

It looks like JSR-303 pretty much defines annotations I would need for declaration part.
And it looks like [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/412.html) is an implementation for actual validator that uses these annotations.
But documentation covers use case where it is used with Hibernate, so I am not sure if it could be used outside Hibernate itself. Since I do not do any database access for the service in question, I would prefer not including other parts of Hibernate.

Has anyone done this or have good pointers to samples?

Alternatively, if anyone knows of another good JSR-303 implementation that would work as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate Validator can be used at any layers. However automatic validation will not happen in your case. So you have to trigger the validation programmatically.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I also learnt this from articles like:

http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com/2009/01/getting-started-with-jsr-303-beans.html

Calling validation is actually quite easy.

Thanks!